# Where is the CTS Pin on Adafruit Bluefruit LE

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, embedded, atmega

We have recently got `adafruit bluefruit le` which looks like
[image]

Now we are interfacing it with `Lilypad ATMEGA 328` as the same shown below link::
[LilyPad interfacing with bluefruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-flora-bluefruit-le/overview)

For configuration of bluefruit we are using [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-flora-bluefruit-le/atcommand) link.

Here it is mentioned

> connect the CTS pin on the Bluefruit to ground if you are not using it!

But we are not able to find CTS pin on the Bluefruit. 
Please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: This question belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ rather then SO.  Or probably even more appropriate to https://www.adafruit.com/support.

Comment: @Clifford: Thanks i will move it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Flora board CTS pin connected to the ground on hardware level. CTS not used on this board by default.

Comment: Don't answer clearly off-topic questions.